# Как создать свой шаблон для 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нарисовал дизайн, как из него можно сверстать шаблон для Bitrix?

Comment: http://alexvaleev.ru/sozdaem-shablon-bitrix/

Answer (score 3):

У Битрикса есть документация по интеграции. Если внимательно почитаете, то, думаю, что все поймете. Там описывается почти все нужное, структура шаблона, включаемые области и работа с компонентами. [Вот она](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/files/manuals/ru/BSM_quick_start.pdf).

При желании можно даже попробовать пройти тест и получить сертификат.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала установить демо, найти папку templates, там будет 2 файла верх и низ. Разрезаете свою верстку и кладете в эти 2 файла. Единственное, что надо почитать - то это системные пути до файлов типа css и js.